# SSRS/RDLC Calculating SubTotal of an Expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc

[image]

This is the desired result Ineeded. 
I had populated State(RowGroup), Male(ColGroup), Year(ColGroup) and the data inside the matrix. To calculate the data count total(100), I used the feature AddTotal by right-clicking it.
But in this report I have used expression to calculated individual Percentage.

Expr1: to calculate the percentage I used this expression:

```
=Fields!count.Value/Sum(Fields!count.Value, "Gender_Group")
```

I have no problem in populating this percentage(25%,25%).

The problem I am right now is calculating the total percentage. (50%).
I couldn't see the AddTotal option in rdlc at the Total field row.

[image]

Hence I tried to add another expression at the red colored cell to find the sum

```
expr2:=Sum(ReportItems!Textbox1.Value)
```

where textbox1 is the value in the Expr1.

But I get an error:

```
Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers.
```

My desired output is finding the total percentage. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just duplicated your report and the following code worked for the expression:

```
Sum(Fields!count.Value)/Sum(Fields!count.Value, "Gender_Group")
```